# Chemical potential of graphene : is $1~\rm eV $ too high?

Tags: graphene, chemical-potential

I am working on graphene plasmonics and I read the following paper that discusses graphene nanoantennas.

https://www.osapublishing.org/oe/abstract.cfm?uri=oe-21-3-3737

They use a chemical potential of $1~\rm eV$and a scattering rate of $0.1~\rm meV$. I simulated structures with lower chemical potentials ($0.2-0.6~\rm eV$) and they don't give as high an efficiency as discussed in the paper. So I was wondering if that value is too high/impractical to consider since most of the other papers report chemical potential of graphene in the range $0.2-0.6~\rm eV. $

1. Is there a practical upper limit on graphene's chemical potential? Why do most of the papers use values between $0.2-0.6~\rm eV$ ?
2. Are the parameters used in the paper too generous/optimistic to be of any practical value? How is the use of such a high chemical potential in the paper justified?

Any insight would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the chemical potential for electrons? What most physicists would term Fermi level?

Comment: Yes I mean Fermi level.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the references here offhand, but their material parameters do seem optimistic.  I believe 1 eV is possible with chemical doping (NO$_2$, for example) or intercalation, but to get this with such a low scattering rate is a little hard to swallow.  One of the downsides to having a single monolayer material is that anything above or below the sheet can dramatically affect the electron scattering/conductivity, and the charge transfer complexes formed by these chemical adsorbates definitely act as scatterers.  Furthermore, you get more scattering at high Fermi energies even for pristine encapsulated/suspended graphene simply because the density of states near the Fermi level increases.  So you are right to be skeptical.  I can't answer if that precise combination of Fermi level and scattering rate is possible, but for further reading, try the graphene plasmonics literature, including [Frank Koppens](https://www.icfo.eu/research/groups-details?group_id=31).